# sys.application and sys.webforms is undefined

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a master page ,A page(aspx) and  A control(ascx)

### error messages

I am getting three errors on the page.

```
1. Sys.Application is undefined
at this line (function() {var fn = function() {$get...);})();Sys.Application.initialize(); 
2. Sys.Application is undefined
[Break On This Error] (function() {var fn = function() {$get...};Sys.Application.add_load(fn);})(); 
3.Sys.WebForms is undefined
[Break On This Error] var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
```

---

I have pasted the code relavent to the the error message.

Code in the Control --------

```
jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        BlockUI("<%=pnlAddEdit.ClientID %>");
        jQuery.blockUI.defaults.css = {};
    });
    function BlockUI(elementID) {
        var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance(); //error at this line
        prm.add_beginRequest(function () {
            jQuery("#" + elementID).block({ message: '<table  align = "center" border=1><tr><td>' +
     '<img src="images/loadingAnim.gif"/></td></tr></table>',
                css: {},
                overlayCSS: { backgroundColor: '#f1f1f1', opacity: 12.2
                }
            });
        });
        prm.add_endRequest(function () {
            jQuery("#" + elementID).unblock();
        });
    }
```

Code in the master page ------------

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
```

Code in Aspx page -----------

```
<%@ Register     Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"     Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"     TagPrefix="asp" %>
```

---

How can I resolve this. I have no Idea. please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is come because you do not have include the `asp:ScriptManager` on your page, or you call this function before this ScriptManager load their script.

So if you have inlcude the `asp:ScriptManager` on your page, the second think that you can do is to call them after the page have been loaded (on PageLoad).

The better place to add your script manager call is on the master page.

Comment: Hi Thank you for the reply. I can see some light now.

Comment: Sorry My above message wasnt complete. I have added <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="toolscripManager1" runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>

Comment: to my aspx page. That helped in fireforx and not in internet explorer. I still get the same error messages . the messages are slighly different though                         Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'add_init': object is null or undefined

Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'PageRequestManager': object is null or undefined

Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'remove_load': object is null or undefined . seems like sys.application is still undefined . Well thank you for the reply.

Comment: @user1453297 the slide different that you say, is totally different. What is the actually error ? can you check your code and understand the next issue ? from what you say me I can not understand it.

Comment: Hi Aristos, I am getting 3 errors at the same line as in Firebug. Firebug stopped showing those errors but IE9 still continues the same way. I get popups with the above error messages when I visit that particular page with the script which says document.ready(function(){ I tried adding the script manager in Master Page also but no luck :(

Comment: @user1453297 I see now again your code and you do not need to add it on document ready, so remove this, is all ready on jQuery ready, and only keep the scriptmanager

Comment: I commented jQuery(document).ready(function () { now my code reads ....    jQuery.noConflict();  BlockUI("<%=pnlAddEdit.ClientID %>"); jQuery.blockUI.defaults.css = {}; ----------------- I still get those three popups with Jquery errors ?

Comment: I observerd one more thing here is I am not getting the error if I move the code and script into aspx page from ascx. But I need to make this work in ascx only.